# Adding ToolbarItems to MainPage.xaml.cs in a Xamarin.Forms Project

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

As described in the title I am looking to add a ToolbarItem to my MainPage.xaml.cs in a Xamarin.Forms Project.

This is because I want an Actionbar on my Android App.

This to my knowledge is available on a NavigationPage.

I have not been able to set my Mainpage as a NavigationPage despite many attempts, it appears it will not let me set it as anything other than a ContentPage.

So far the best information I can find on this subject is here:

[xamarin.forms not showing ToolbarItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60691922/xamarin-forms-not-showing-toolbaritem)

This however does not answer my question as it is relevant to App.xaml.cs not MainPage.xaml.cs

And my project is a multi-platform Xamarin.Forms for building apps apps for IOS and Android with Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms project.

Currently however I'm just focusing on Android in the shared C# project (MainPage.xaml.cs).

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi can you show how you navigate from App.xaml.cs to your MainPage?

Comment: add your app.xaml.cs file

Comment: Hi, could you please expand on what you mean as I do not at all use App.xaml.cs only Mainpage.xaml.cs

Comment: How can I add my App.xaml.cs file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Described in Wendy's answer the following code is required:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

However she forgot the mention this code needs to be added to App.xaml.cs not MainPage.xaml.cs file.

This file is present in the C# Project for a Xamarin.Forms mobile app.

You can find it by clicking the drop down arrow in the 'Solution Explorer' on the 'App.xaml' file to find the 'App.xaml.cs' file.

If you can't find it type it in the search bar on the 'Solution Explorer'.

And edit the MainPage = new MainPage(); code in the file to MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());

Answer (score 0):

The ToolbarItems needs a Navigation Page to show them up. So modify your MainPage wrapped by a navigation page:

**App.xaml.cs:**

```
  public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    }
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the reply Wendy. I have tried the coded in your answer in the public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {

        public MainPage()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
           MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage()); This is not working for me however as I recieve the error CS0118 'MainPage' is a type but is used like a variable.

Comment: The code shows the toolbar item. What do you want to know more for this?

Comment: I need more detail as I have tried that solution before and it did not work I recieve the error as follows CS0118 'MainPage' is a type but is used like a variable.

Comment: Could you provide the code for this CS0118 error message?

Comment: Hi Wendy, thank you for the help. I managed to figure out what the problem was, I needed the code you presented in the answer. However I had put it in the Mainpage.xaml.cs. The code needed to be in the App.xaml.cs which I was not aware of as a beginner Xamarin.Forms users. Could you please make this clear in your answer? thank you